# How to Ping External IP from Java Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing a Ping application for Android 2.2.

I try my code and it works, but only in local IPs, that's my problem I want to do ping to external servers too.

Here is my code:

```
  private OnClickListener milistener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        Editable host = edit.getText();
        InetAddress in;
        in = null;
        // Definimos la ip de la cual haremos el ping
        try {
            in = InetAddress.getByName(host.toString());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Definimos un tiempo en el cual ha de responder
        try {
            if (in.isReachable(5000)) {
                info.setText("Responde OK");
            } else {
                info.setText("No responde: Time out");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            info.setText(e.toString());
        }
    }
};
```

> Ping 127.0.0.1 -> OK 
>   Ping 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS) -> Time Out

I put the following line at Manifest XML too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Can anyone suggest me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: More information too ^^ Do you test it in the Emulator or on a real device? Do you have internet connection enabled? i.e. on a real device make sure the "mobile network" is activated and that you have an internet connection

Comment: I tested in the Emulator and on a Real Device connected to the internet. Thanks.

Comment: Did you come right with this issue? I am having the same problem. If you got around this problem, could you also advise me. Regards
Sanjay

Comment: I am also facing same problem can you please provide solution to this if you found!

Comment: got to this link , i got answer from this,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576710/ping-application-in-android/

Answer (score 61):

I tried following code, which works for me.

```
private boolean executeCommand(){
        System.out.println("executeCommand");
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try
        {
            Process  mIpAddrProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
            int mExitValue = mIpAddrProcess.waitFor();
            System.out.println(" mExitValue "+mExitValue);
            if(mExitValue==0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ignore)
        {
            ignore.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(" Exception:"+ignore);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(" Exception:"+e);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I found this is the only reliable way to check ICMP echo on 4.1.

Comment: Do you need special permissions to run this?

Comment: Can someone please explain this? How does checking for "mExitValue" makes sure that ping was successful?

Comment: Checking the exit value of a command is useful because exit 0 generically  means the command was successful. Any other value suggests an issue.

Comment: This leaks memory when put into service and recursively call it!
You need to manually close stdin, stdout and stderr file descriptors.

runtime.getInputStream().close();
runtime.getOutputStream().close();
runtime.getErrorStream().close();

Use this command to check for pipe leaks:

adb shell ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd. Please edit the answer and add stream closes, I crashed at this intended behaviour for days..

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this will always return true right? Doesn't  ping always executes successfully regardless of the connection? It is just the output that changes. I thought. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @ChadBingham Well, for me `ping` returns `1` if it was unable to reach the server, so it would appear that the exit code does in fact change, at least on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 25):

This is a simple ping I use in one of the projects:

```java
public static class Ping {
    public String net = "NO_CONNECTION";
    public String host = "";
    public String ip = "";
    public int dns = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    public int cnt = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}

public static Ping ping(URL url, Context ctx) {
    Ping r = new Ping();
    if (isNetworkConnected(ctx)) {
        r.net = getNetworkType(ctx);
        try {
            String hostAddress;
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            hostAddress = InetAddress.getByName(url.getHost()).getHostAddress();
            long dnsResolved = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Socket socket = new Socket(hostAddress, url.getPort());
            socket.close();
            long probeFinish = System.currentTimeMillis();
            r.dns = (int) (dnsResolved - start);
            r.cnt = (int) (probeFinish - dnsResolved);
            r.host = url.getHost();
            r.ip = hostAddress;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Timber.e("Unable to ping");
        }
    }
    return r;
}

public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}

@Nullable
public static String getNetworkType(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null) {
        return activeNetwork.getTypeName();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage: `ping(new URL("https://www.google.com:443/"), this);`

Result: `{"cnt":100,"dns":109,"host":"www.google.com","ip":"212.188.10.114","net":"WIFI"}`

Comment: This pings a specific port while the other solutions use the ICMP ping (not port specific). So this is an interesting alternative. I guess, root permissions are not required?

Comment: Root access is not required but `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`should be in the manifest.

Answer (score 11):

Run the ping utility in Android's command and parse output (assuming you have root permissions)

See the following Java code snippet:

```
executeCmd("ping -c 1 -w 1 google.com", false);

public static String executeCmd(String cmd, boolean sudo){
    try {

        Process p;
        if(!sudo)
            p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        else{
            p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", cmd});
        }
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String s;
        String res = "";
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            res += s + "\n";
        }
        p.destroy();
        return res;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";

}
```

Comment: I'm doing ping -c 10 (10 pings averaged) Would it be possible to display line by line? I tried having it append s to a TextView where it would normally append s to res but that didn't work.

Answer (score 9):

In my case ping works from device but not from the emulator. I found this documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

On the topic of "Local Networking Limitations" it says:

> "Depending on the environment, the emulator may not be able to support
>   other protocols (such as ICMP, used for "ping") might not be
>   supported. Currently, the emulator does not support IGMP or
>   multicast."

Further information:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8657506be6819297

> this is a known limitation of the QEMU user-mode network stack.
>   Quoting from  the original doc:  Note that ping is not supported
>   reliably to the internet as it would require  root privileges. It
>   means you can only ping the local router (10.0.2.2).

Answer (score 5):

Ping for the google server or any other server

```
public boolean isConecctedToInternet() {

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int     exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);
    } catch (IOException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: From Which version of android this code will work? Will it work on android 4.1+

Comment: This is not an universal solution, because it relies on external utility.

Comment: keep in mind that the ping binary is not necessarily going to exist on every device.  It's up to the manufacturer to include it and not everyone does.

Answer (score 4):

I implemented "ping" in pure Android Java and hosted it on gitlab. It does the same thing as the ping executable, but is much easier to configure.  It's has a couple useful features like being able to bind to a given Network.

https://github.com/dburckh/AndroidPing

Answer (score 2):

This is what I implemented myself, which returns the average latency:

```
/*
Returns the latency to a given server in mili-seconds by issuing a ping command.
system will issue NUMBER_OF_PACKTETS ICMP Echo Request packet each having size of 56 bytes
every second, and returns the avg latency of them.
Returns 0 when there is no connection
 */
public double getLatency(String ipAddress){
    String pingCommand = "/system/bin/ping -c " + NUMBER_OF_PACKTETS + " " + ipAddress;
    String inputLine = "";
    double avgRtt = 0;

    try {
        // execute the command on the environment interface
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pingCommand);
        // gets the input stream to get the output of the executed command
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while ((inputLine != null)) {
            if (inputLine.length() > 0 && inputLine.contains("avg")) {  // when we get to the last line of executed ping command
                break;
            }
            inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "getLatency: EXCEPTION");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Extracting the average round trip time from the inputLine string
    String afterEqual = inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf("="), inputLine.length()).trim();
    String afterFirstSlash = afterEqual.substring(afterEqual.indexOf('/') + 1, afterEqual.length()).trim();
    String strAvgRtt = afterFirstSlash.substring(0, afterFirstSlash.indexOf('/'));
    avgRtt = Double.valueOf(strAvgRtt);

    return avgRtt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ICMP packets are blocked by your (mobile) provider. If this code doesn't work on the emulator try to sniff via wireshark or any other sniffer and have a look whats up on the wire when you fire the isReachable() method.

You may also find some info in your device log.

Comment: I have tested in a Android 2.2 Tablet connected via Wifi i dont use any Momile Provider. Thanks.

Comment: Then your next step should be to sniff the traffic (not) generated by your device. There are many things which could went wrong here...

Comment: It's unlikely that it's cause by blocked ICMP, as the Android documentation says that `InetAddress.isReachable` first tries to ping via ICMP if that fails it tries to ping on TCP port 7 (Echo)

Comment: According to http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/libcore.git;a=blob;f=luni/src/main/java/java/net/InetAddress.java;hb=HEAD ICMP will not be used if you don't specify an interface. isReachable only uses the TCP Echo stuff, seems to be some strange behavior or a firewalling problem or something else... Are you sure you are able to access the internet from your application? Ever tried to recieve a file via HTTP?

Comment: how can I test that my app can access to the internet??

Comment: Seems that the "isReachableByMultiThread" doesn't even try ICMP at the moment. Comment in code: "Spec violation! This implementation doesn't attempt an ICMP; it skips right to TCP echo." - Shame...

Comment: @Andrioid, for raw socket (ICMP) you need root to do it, it's the same in java. the ping command both on *nix/windows actually runs w/ root/admin priviliges

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple code to get latency in kotlin: less if, using `ip`:String as input, using regex to split format, using `avg` for latency in `ms`

```
    var avg = LATENCY_ERROR
    val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 $ip")
    BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.inputStream)).forEachLine {
        // it: "PING 194.194.194.194 (194.194.194.194) 56(84) bytes of data."
        // it: "rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 326.137/326.137/326.137/0.000 ms"
        if (it.contains("rtt ")) {
            avg = Regex("\\d+\\.\\d+").findAll(it).toList()[1].value.toFloat().roundToInt()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice and simple.  But don't forget to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your manifest!

Answer (score 0):

To get the boolean value for the hit on the ip

```
public Boolean getInetAddressByName(String name)
    {
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>()
        {

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
                try
                {
                    return InetAddress.getByName(params[0]).isReachable(2000);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
        try {
            return task.execute(name).get();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return null;
        }
        catch (ExecutionException e) {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**2024 update for anyone interested in ICMP ping/echo for Android**

[icmp4a library](https://github.com/marsounjan/icmp4a) (my library) is much better and effective alternative to invoking `ping` command via Runtime process builder.

Example:

1. **Get the library**

```
implementation "com.marsounjan:icmp4a:1.0.0"
```

2. **Single ICMP Ping**

```
val icmp = Icmp4a()
val host = "google.com"
try {
  val status = icmp.ping( host = "8.8.8.8")
  val result = status.result
  when (result) {
    is Icmp.PingResult.Success -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) ${result.packetSize} bytes - ${result.ms} ms")
    is Icmp.PingResult.Failed -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) Failed: ${result.message}")
  }
} catch (error: Icmp.Error.UnknownHost) {
  Log.d("ICMP", "Unknown host $host")
}
```

Logcat output

```
2024-01-26 16:22:48.515 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 12 ms
```

3. **Multiple ICMP Pings with specified interval**

```
val icmp = Icmp4a()
val host = "google.com"
try {
  icmp.pingInterval(
      "8.8.8.8",
      count = 5,
      intervalMillis = 1000
  )
    .onEach { status ->
        val result = status.result
        when (result) {
          is Icmp.PingResult.Success -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) ${result.packetSize} bytes - ${result.ms} ms")
          is Icmp.PingResult.Failed -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) Failed: ${result.message}")
        }
    }
      .launchIn(viewModelScope)
} catch (error: Icmp.Error.UnknownHost) {
  Log.d("ICMP", "Unknown host $host")
}
```

Logcat output

```
2024-01-26 16:29:16.633 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 15 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:17.577 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 17 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:18.598 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 17 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:19.614 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 15 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:20.630 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 13 ms
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this Code: this method works on 4.3+ and also for below versions too.

```
   try {

         Process process = null;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 16) {
            // shiny APIS 
               process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "/system/bin/ping -w 1 -c 1 " + url);


        } 
        else 
        {

                   process = new ProcessBuilder()
                 .command("/system/bin/ping", url)
                 .redirectErrorStream(true)
                 .start();

            }



        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getInputStream()));

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        String temp;

        while ( (temp = reader.readLine()) != null)//.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            output.append(temp);
            count++;
        }

        reader.close();


        if(count > 0)
            str = output.toString();

        process.destroy();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i("PING Count", ""+count);
    Log.i("PING String", str);
```

Answer (score -2):

**Pink ip Address**

```
  public static int pingHost(String host, int timeout) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    timeout /= 1000;
    String cmd = "ping -c 1 -W " + timeout + " " + host;
    Process proc = runtime.exec(cmd);
    Log.d(TAG, cmd);
    proc.waitFor();
    int exit = proc.exitValue();
    return exit;
}
   Ping a host and return an int value of 0 or 1 or 2 0=success, 1=fail,
   * 2=error
```