# Ping Test Android

Tags: java, android

I am working on developing ping application.In terms of ICMP, is there any proper ping API for android application in order to count the number of packets?

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451200/how-to-icmp-ping-on-android

Answer (score 0):

try

> Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping www.google.com");

and read output from p.getOutputStream()

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started development on 'jpingy' a java ping library.

Maybe it does already some stuff what you want. More to come!

http://code.google.com/p/jpingy/