# Calculation of Estimated time of arrival

Tags: android

How can we calculate the Estimated time of arrival of wifi-signals..i need to check at what time do i get a signal from my wifi router..is pinging to the router one method??...Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** *My suggestion covers just one half of your question. The other half can be perhaps achieved by the link posted at the bottom.*

I think you will want to start with getting the IP address of the router (the default gateway) you will need to ping.

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
DhcpInfo dhcpInfo =wifiMgr.getDhcpInfo();
String strGateway = String.valueOf(dhcpInfo.gateway);
```

And I think you will need these permissions in the Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

And for checking the estimated time, try using this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9991264/450534. It is pretty detailed and *I think* it should get you set up. Also on the same page, is a link to the [Android Terminal Emulator source](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator). That could be useful too. Props to the original authors.

The first part I have used and it works. The second part, however, was never necessary for me and therefore, never attempted.

Comment: @user22: Glad it did. And glad to have helped. :-)

Comment: well bt i am facing a problem.....i studied about the dhcp class,it says that it returns ip address of dhcp request,bt apparently its returning me the ip address of my android phone and not the access point.Thanks

Comment: @user22: Well the code gets you the routers IP address. This bit here `dhcpInfo.gateway` takes care of it. I have always got the right IP address.

Comment: yes...its works....actually it returns ip address as the gateway address....so i was a bit confused coz it was also returning something called as iPaddr.....so thanks a lot..

Comment: @IceMan...well i am getting the ip address....bt my InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress).isReachable alwz returns false