# Can i ping to my PC from my mobile and Vice versa?

Tags: android, sockets, ping

My android mobile and PC are connected using USB.
Now can i ping to my PC from my mobile?Is this possible?
And also can i ping to my mobile from PC? If so, using what IP, i should ping my Mobile?
Note:

- My HTC mobile and PC are not in same network.
- HTC mobile have GSM net connection.
- Below i have added my sample code to ping PC and HTC mobile

Eg:

client code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("10.51.2.98", 1234);//trying to ping my PC ip address
```

server code:

```
channel.sin_family = AF_INET; 
channel.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
channel.sin_port = htons(1234);
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905358/how-to-ping-external-ip-from-java-android

Answer (score 0):

1st - your code would not ping anywhere - but rather create a TCP socket (see [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol)).

2nd - USB does not usually give you a network interface (it is possible, but rarely the default type of connection), but some other profile such as mass storage device, and you need a networking interface to generate ping messages.