# Exist some way in java for android, to detect the faster download link and choose the faster?

Tags: java, android, performance, download

Exist some way in java for android, to detect the faster download url and choose the faster?

Example i have two urls for the same thing, and i want to choose the faster according to different location, that may have one faster than another.

Comment: have you done any research?

Comment: yes, but i don't found. i already make the download, but i wanna choose the best from a list.

Answer (score 0):

How about you ping to a website from your app and keep track of time spent in receiving a response?

See [How to ping a website from an Android activity and get response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873489/how-to-ping-a-website-from-android-activity-and-get-response)

you can use startTime and endTime variables in the code and compare the difference.

```
 try{ 
    Log.e("checking", "Checking network connection...");
    //startTime
    httpClient.execute(httpGet);
   //EndTime
    Log.e("checking", "Connection OK");
    return; 
}
```

Comment: Yes probably is a good ideia, i have link an array of urls and i want to choose the best. i go to try

Comment: awesome! do share your results

Comment: ping just sometimes get the better way.

Comment: i didnt get what you mean?

Comment: I use a temp file to download the link for one second and compare the data transfered.