# How to make a ping in Android to Google

Tags: android

I'm trying to find the way to know when an user has Internet connection, since now I've got this method :

```
public boolean isNetworkOnline() {
    boolean status=false;
    try{
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(1);
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            status= true;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return status;
}
```

This method returns true if user is `CONNECTED` but not if user has `INTERNET CONNECTION`, so I thought to if this method returns true, call another method to check if the user has connection to internet. For example someone can be connected to a router but without internet connection so I want to know when the user has internet connection or not.

I've read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11525981/4385913) and this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25460809/4385913) but all of them is returning me `false` when I've got `Internet connection`.... I thought that make a method that makes a ping to `www.google.com` it's a good approach to know if someone has internet connection so I tried to get this way but it didn't work for me...

Any idea or good approach (if it's better than my thoughts is better) to know when the user has internet connection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android check internet connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this method?

```
public boolean checkInternectConnection() {
        try {
            InetAddress inAddress= InetAddress.getByName("http://google.com");
            if (inAddress.equals("")) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let me check... hold on

Comment: Shall I put this method on a Thread? Cause it doesn't give time to return true or not.... how should I do this?

Comment: Yes, better if you can use `AsyncTask` to perform this check. Because `NetworkOnMainThreadException` will occur if you try to do it inside your main activity thread. You can refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662805/inetaddress-in-android) for information about doing it.

Comment: This solution yields UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "http://google.com": No address associated with hostname for me

Answer (score 3):

**The Simple Way To Check Internet Connectivity**

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
        if (networkConnectivity()) {
            try {
                Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                        "ping -c 1 www.google.com");
                int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
                boolean reachable = (returnVal == 0);
                if (reachable) {
                    System.out.println("Internet access");
                    return reachable;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        } else
            return false;

    }

    private boolean networkConnectivity() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) _context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

---

**How To Call it**

```
  if (isConnectingToInternet()) {

       // internet is connected and work properly...
    }
else {

    // something  went wrong internet not working properly...
}
```

So simply copy and past the above two methods where you want to check the Internet connectivity. After that check the condition `if (isConnectingToInternet()) { }`

Comment: simply copy and past the above two method where u want to check the Internet connectivity

Comment: after that check the condition 
if (isConnectingToInternet()) {
    }

Comment: sorry by mistake i put the code in separate  class and then call it with 
new i edit  my answer now you can try it

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I Edit my Answer now Check it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786720/android-service-ping-url) answer out and see if its helpful or not

You can try out this code

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://"+params[0]);

    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Application:"+Z.APP_VERSION);
    urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 30); // mTimeout is in seconds
    urlc.connect();

    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        Main.Log("getResponseCode == 200");
        return new Boolean(true);
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It must be on a thread right? Since this has the `setConnectionTimeout()` right?

Answer (score 1):

this is how i fixed this and i use it as a Utility method which can be called from any activity/fragment etc...:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                    = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
        }//check if Wifi or Mobile data is enabled


private static class NetworkAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)
                    (new URL("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204")
                            .openConnection());
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1500);
            urlConnection.connect();
            return (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 204 &&
                    urlConnection.getContentLength() == 0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Error checking internet connection
        }
        return false;
    }
}//network calls shouldn't be called from main thread otherwise it will throw //NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

and now you simply need to call this method from anywhere you want:

```
public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {
        if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
            try {
                //used execute().get(); so that it gets awaited and returns the result 
                //after i receive a response
                return new NetworkAsync().execute().get();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```