# Android Application Ping IP number

Tags: android

Working with Android Application, the user enter a network IP number inside a editview Ex: (192.100.10.10). I want to see if that network IP exist before go further on.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes they have something that half works. But both questions are still essentially "how can I ping in android?".

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look somehow like this:

```
InetAddress in;
//try to parse address
try {
    in = InetAddress.getByName("192.100.10.10");
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    //incorrect IP
}

try {
    //wait for response (500ms)
    if (in.isReachable(5000)) {
        //host reachable
    } else {
        //no host found/timeout
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // IOException
}
```

credit goes to [How to Ping External IP from Java Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905358/how-to-ping-external-ip-from-java-android)