# Ping local IP in Android studio

Tags: android, ping

I'm trying to develop a method that checks if an IP direction is reachable and I found a similar question but it doesn't work
[Android Application Ping IP number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889503/android-application-ping-ip-number)

```
private void existePingServidor(){
    InetAddress in;
       try{
            in = InetAddress.getByName("90.0.0.122");

       if (in.isReachable(5000)){
           pingServidor = true;
           Log.v("true","He pasado por aquí");
       }
       else
           pingServidor = false;
       Log.v("false", "No he podido alcanzar la ip");

    }

    catch(Exception  e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem seems that InetAddress.getByName("90.0.0.122"); returns null

¿Can you explain me what is the proper way to ping a Ip in android studio please?

Comment: Something good to know, `Log.v("false", "No he podido alcanzar la ip");` will always get called because you aren't using brackets correctly in the else-statement.

Comment: Also, could you explain why you want to ping a site to check if it's available? Your problem might be solvable in an easier way.

Comment: Hi, thank for your answer, it's true about the log, but i get an android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException that causes the Log to not display anything. About the reassons of checking the IP is because if the IP is the 90.0.0.122 then the aplication has to do other things.

Comment: Call the function in a separate thread. There are a lot of questions about NetworkOnMainThreadException on Google. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 1):

Try getByAddress instead:

```
    byte [] ip = {90, 0, 0, 122};
    addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
    addr.isReachable(5000);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but still getting the same problem, the Log.v is not executed.