# The best way for checking internet connection in android

Tags: android, network-programming

I want to check internet connection when device is connected to a network but that doesnt have internet connection.
I want to know what is the best way for checking this

I asked this question because didn't find any accept answer is SO.
here are some duplicate questions but there isn't one accept answer:

[Java: Internet connectivity check via ping to google not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473768/java-internet-connectivity-check-via-ping-to-google-not-working)

[Check for Active internet connection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717749/check-for-active-internet-connection-android)

also two questions that has accepted answer, the answers are not working fine:

[Android check internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection)

[Test Internet Connection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575030/test-internet-connection-android)

Comment: To downvoter: Could you please explain your downvote. This is a perfectly legit question for some user cases.

Comment: obviously, @f470071 because it is a duplicate of bazillion similar questions, here on SO ... and ahmad didn't do any research ...

Comment: @Selvin , please read again the question.
can you show me an accepted answer that works fine???

Comment: I don't think you understand that it is impossible to reliably detect Internet access. No system can detect the difference between a server that is not responding (even though you have Internet access) and a connection that is blocked (no Internet). All the existing methods just try to ping a server which is likely to be available.

Answer (score 1):

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

This way you can determine if you have internet access or not - no need to fight with ping request or something like that.

Comment: One should not confuse network access and internet access. You can easily be on a WiFi with no outside connection.

Comment: I know. That's why this code does check for internet connection, and not WiFi access.

Comment: not working! isConnected become true when wifi is connected but has no internet!

Comment: This is the official example code from the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) about exactly your problem.

Answer (score -2):

```
Use the below class to check whether internet is available or not.
```

For Reference: [click here to check the example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/)

ConnectionDetector.Java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {

private Context _context;

public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
    this._context = context;
}

public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)   _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null) 
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null) 
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
}
}
```

Comment: its return true, when wifi is connected but has no internet connectivity!

Comment: Then Try this example.But used the above example in my project.http://androidexample.com/Check_Internet_Connectivity/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=99&aaid=121