# wifi is connected and internet is not available iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, reachability

My question is same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565530/check-internet-is-connected-on-device-or-not-when-wifi-is-enable), but don't get a proper answer.

If I am connected to wifi, but internet is not available/gone it should be notify. Alslo tested using [Apple Reachability demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) but still its not working.

Steps to reproduce:

1) connect iPhone using tethering on another device.

2) run the apple rechability demo.

3) turn off the cellular data on another device on wich iPhone is connected.

Comment: Did you try to connect to an host or an IP Address with Reachability?

Comment: yup tried using host name

Comment: I think it's a problem that's a device has tethering on and cellular data off... Anyway a wifi connection can be for internal private network that doesn't connected to the internet... I don't understand what you are asking...

Comment: Follow above steps for check for cellular data, and for check wifi internet remove internet cable, will same problem like  cellular data

Comment: I'm pretty sure Reachability doesn't support this case.

Comment: oops !!     is there any other way, because other apps are doing !!!!

Answer (score -2):

You can simply call the below code and then call NSURLConnection delegate methods. This way even if wifi is connected and internet not available it can be detected.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *headerRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];
    headerRequest.HTTPMethod = @"HEAD";
    self.headerConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:headerRequest delegate:self];
```

Comment: That's fine, but how can I notified when internet is gone ?

Comment: You don't.  In iOS, the proper thing to do is attempt your network operation and pay attention to errors.