# Android some network job(ping) doesn't work

Tags: android, networking

I am developing an android application.
It uses some network service like:

- Firebase Firestore
- 3rd party REST API
- Ping.

When I develop this, everything works fine.
So I tested it on my phone, and I uploaded it in the play store.
After uploaded to the play store, I tried to download and tested.
But ping is only failed!!!

I cannot understand this situation.

First, Firebase Firestore works fine.

Second, I am using 3rd party REST API. To using the service, I am using "Retrofit" library.
It works fine too.

Third, my app has the feature to check server status.
For this feature, I implemented "ping".
This is just ping.

> "ping -c 1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

And show the latency to the end user.
It works fine in debug/release/signed APK.

**But it doesn't work when I download from the play store.**

I just added only one permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Should I define ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission too?
But Firestore and other 3rd party REST API works fine.

---

Below is my 'build.gradle' file.

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias xxx
            keyPassword xxx
            storeFile xxx
            storePassword 'xxx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 16
        versionName "1.1.7"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

And my "proguard-rules.pro" file is empty.

Below is my code to get the ping information.

```
    public static String ping(String host) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = runtime.exec("ping -c 1 -w 3 " + host);
    proc.waitFor();
    int exit = proc.exitValue();

    if (exit == 0) {
        StringBuffer echo = new StringBuffer();
        try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()))) {
            String line = "";
            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                echo.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }

        return getPingStats(echo.toString());
    } else if (exit == 1) {
        pingError = "failed, exit = 1";
        Log.e(TAG, "[CHICKEN] ping - error: " + pingError);
        return null;
    } else {
        pingError = "error, exit = 2";
        Log.e(TAG, "[CHICKEN] ping - error: " + pingError);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use proguard for your release APK?

Comment: @DavidRawson I edit question with my "build.gradle" file. And I don't use the "proguard" anywhere.

Comment: @DavidRawson Sorry, I edit my question again. Other network service works fine. (Firebase Firestore, REST API) Only Ping doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using the methods in this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905358/how-to-ping-external-ip-from-java-android

Comment: @DavidRawson I updated with my "ping" code.