# Android: wait for network connectivity to make an API call

Tags: android

In my project, the requirement is to click a button to upload some images to the server by make an API call. However, the tricky part is that we assume the user may be in a place where network is not available. So there should be a way that always check the network connectivity. Only if the network is available then execute that upload images intent service.

Could you tell me what should I use? RxJava? BroadcastReceiver or something else? What is the best practice to handle this issue?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: just use retrofit...onFailure handle the issue..

Comment: as @SantanuSur said use Retrofit....if you can'nt this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/48735424/9130109

Comment: As the comments above say, use Retrofit and OkHttp

Answer (score 2):

One of the best practice ways to handle this would be do dispatch the image uploading job using Android's [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html) API.  The JobScheduler will allow you to set conditions that the job must meet before the job is dispatched, one of which is network connectivity conditions.

Also, if you're targeting a lower API level and JobScheduler isn't available, the [GCMNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager) is also an option.

Comment: To use a single api on different api versions, consider android-job library from evernote. https://github.com/evernote/android-job

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ConnectivityManager** class , with a simple alert dialogue , in order to make sure that user is having internet connection , for example:

```
private NetworkState mNetworkState;
        mNetworkState = new NetworkState(mContext);
            if (!mNetworkState.isConnected()) {
            /**
             If application is not connected to the internet , then
             display dialog message and finish.
             */
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            mContext);
            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("This application needs internet connection.")
            .setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Got it!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
/**
  In my case i close the current activity , by calling finish() 
 */
MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
    });
    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
    } else {
    /**
     YOUR CODE GOES HERE :
     */
    }
```

and for **Network State** class will be :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
// This class for accessing network state for our application
public class NetworkState {

private final ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager;


public NetworkState(Context context) {
    mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
}

public boolean isConnected() {
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
} }
```